# Can I leave the airport during a 24-hours layover, traveling to Greece through Frankfurt, using a national D visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration

I'm from Tunisia and I have a student visa (type D) to study in Greece. This is my first travel and it will be in August. My itinerary is as follows:

Tunisia ---> Frankfurt international airport --> 24-hour layover  --> Athens

I'm wondering if it's possible to leave the airport to spend the night in a hotel and use the remaining hours until my next flight to explore the city of Frankfurt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can leave the airport.  You will have to pass through immigration controls in Frankfurt in any event to reach your departure gate.  You must therefore do so even if you don't leave the airport, and you will not pass through immigration controls in Greece.

Your flight from Germany to Greece is an internal Schengen flight, effectively a domestic flight.  Therefore after you return to the airport you will not pass through a passport control checkpoint.